# Win32 - cannot trigger WM_PAINT message with RedrawWindow()

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I am trying to trigger a WM_PAINT message form WM_TIMER; the timer works, but RedrawWindow() function does not seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Callback function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
    COLORREF    clrBlue = RGB(25, 55, 200);
    RECT        Recto = { 20, 28, 188, 128 };
    COLORREF    clrAqua = RGB(128, 255, 255);
    COLORREF clrRed  = RGB(255, 25, 5);
    static bool x = true;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }

        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        //InvalidateRect(hWnd ,NULL , FALSE);
        //RedrawWindow(hWnd , NULL , NULL , RDW_INVALIDATE);
        RedrawWindow(hWnd,NULL,NULL,RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        if(x)
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            SetTextColor(hdc, clrRed);
            TextOut(hdc, 50, 42, L"Some text", 13);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            toggle(x);
        }
        else
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            SetTextColor(hdc, clrRed);
            TextOut(hdc, 50, 42, L"Another text", 13);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            toggle(x);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);

        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want an immediate redraw then also try to add the `RDW_UPDATENOW` and/or `RDW_ERASENOW` flags next to your `RDW_INVALIDATE`. BTW, does your `WM_PAINT` handler execute as the result of your `RedrawWindow` call?

Comment: 13 is not correct number of characters in your TextOut call, this might cause Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: InvalidateRect is sufficient for this. Make sure your timer is actually being fired, and make sure that your timer interval is slow enough to let the repainting actually happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `x` is defined as a local variable in your function, it always gets the value `true` when the function is called. That is, the code in `WM_PAINT` never gets to the `else` branch of the `if`.

Try, for example, changing the definition of `x` to `static bool x = true;` to get the toggling work.

Additionally, you need to invalidate the window's contents to get it redrawn:

```
RedrawWindow(hWnd,NULL,NULL,RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
```

Comment: I did, nothing happened

Comment: You also need to invalidate the window - see the updated answer.

Comment: Passing both RDW_INVALIDATE and RDW_INTERNALPAINT seems redundant.